# CSS: Equal side by side containers above certain width and on top of each other when below that width

Tags: html, css

I have two containers.

When the screen is 500px or less these containers need to sit on top of each other, and both take up 100% of the screen.

When the screen is more than 500px they need to be side by side both taking up equal width of the screen horizontal space.

This needs to work in ie8. I can't use media queries.

Is this possible just using CSS? (no JavaScript)

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Yes, it's possible. Just so you know.

Comment: you can use inline media queries in CSS. IT's part of the deal :)

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Then there are js solutions. Only way for the OP to get his wish.

Comment: Sure. I think that is what I'll be doing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible in browsers that support Media Queries, but sadly IE8 does not, though you can get a JS plugin (Respond.js or similar) that will make them work on IE8.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/JzDav/1/) is a working version in browsers that support media queries

The key piece of code is

```
@media 
  screen and (max-device-width: 500px), 
  screen and (max-width: 500px) {
```

Support for Media Queries can be seen [here](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries)

Comment: Yeah if only I didn't have the ie8 restriction, media queries would be definately be the winner. I just wanted to make sure it couldn't be done in CSS before I started with JavaScript :P

Comment: I'd definitely recommend Respond.js if you are going to use JS, it doesn't need any modifying and will work on any browser. It's also pretty small (1kb if i remember correctly)

Comment: Hrm *another* JavaScript library ... It might be overkill seeing as though this is the only thing I need to do. But maybe yes, I'll look into it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Media query

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="dv">First block</div>
<div class="dv2">Second block</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.container{width:500px; background:grey}
.dv{ background:green;  width:500px; height:250px}
.dv2{ background:red;  width:500px; height:250px }

@media screen and (min-width : 500px)
{
    .container{width:100%; background:grey; overflow:auto}
    .dv{width:50%; float:left}    
    .dv2{width:50%; float:left}
}​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wM5zY/2/)